# What to pass? Reference Object or Value Type?

Tags: c#, oop

Guys I have a "best practice question" For example I have this classes:

```
class Person
{
   public int age {get; set;}
}

class Computer
{
   public void checkAge(Person p)  // Which one is recommended   THIS
   {
       // Do smthg with the AGE
   }

   public void checkAge(int p)     // OR THIS
   {
       //Do smthg with the age.
   }
}
```

What is recommended to pass? Just what I need (int-value type) or the whole object (reference type)

Im asking this because Im using LINQ on an app that I am making and I have created many entities where I should pass the IDs (foreing keys), but Im passing objects.

What is the best approach?

Comment: +1 I always had this confusion and somehow went into oblivion,now it's clarified.thanks.

Comment: This is the type of questions that I always have doubts. I needed to ask :D

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The function `checkAge` should only take in the minimum amount of information needed to perform it's job.  Adding anything else just creates an artificial dependency.  If only an `int` is needed then that is the solution I should take.

Comment: Excelent Jared, so I should keep in mind give the minimun information needed.- Sometimes I need to pass 2 ints, I should then give to the function 2 ints and so on right?

Comment: @MRFerocious, I would create 2 functions.  The version that only needs 1 `int` and another which accepts 2 `int`s and has a distinctly different behavior

Comment: This principle is called the Law of Demeter: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter

Answer (score 12):

I would argue that in this case, the answer is probably neither.  Either "Age" would be factored out into its own class, or if the operation is context-specific with Person, it would be found inside the Person class itself.

Answer (score 3):

with the information given, neither solution is good

the first solution requires the Computer class to know about Person.Age, for no apparent reason

the second attaches a method to the Computer class that has nothing to do with the properties of the Computer object

some context would be helpful - if this is a validation, then CheckAge belongs to the Person class (with possibly an IsAgeAcceptable property)

Why is the Computer checking the age of a Person? The answer to this determines what makes sense...

Comment: @Steven A. Lowe - I think the OP is just giving an example. I'm *sure* or hope that he doesn't really have a `checkAge` function within the Computer class.

Comment: hahaha Guys, of course this is just an example. I´m asking this because Im using Linq and I need to pass some ids, but in some cases I have 3, so I decided to pass the objects.- So I will go for passing just the ints.

Answer (score 2):

Follow the law of demeter for functions.  Basically the law states that entities should be loosely coupled.  Ask yourself the following question, should a computer object know about a person object?  In this case, maybe all you are doing inside checkAge is checking an int value.  If that is the case then what makes you think passing the entire object is needed?  Simply pass the person age and take it in as an int in this case.

So prefer

```
public void checkAge(int n)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to point out that when passing a reference, the reference is a 32 bit integer while a data type is copied.  So if your value type is larger that a 32bit int, pass by reference if performance or memory is any sort of issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'd point out that `int Age` is probably not the best way to store that value.
([Why is DateTime a Property and not a Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437972/why-is-datetime-now-a-property-and-not-a-method)
)

```
class Person : IBorn
{
  public DateTime Birth {get; set;}
}

interface IBorn
{
  DateTime Birth {get; set;} 
}

interface IDateTimeFactory
{
  DateTime Now();     
}

class DefaultDateTimeFactory : IDateTimeFactory
{
  public DateTime Now()
  {
    return DateTime.Now;
  }
}

public static class IBornExtensions
{
  public TimeSpan AgeFromNow(this IBorn birthed, IDateTimeFactory dtf)
  {
    return dtf.Now() - birthed.Birth;
  }
  public TimeSpan AgeFrom(this IBorn birthed, DateTime from)
  {
    return from - birthed.Birth;
  }
}

class Computer
{
  public void checkAge(IBorn birthed)        
  {
    var age = birthed.Age((new DefaultDateTimeFactory()).Now());
  }
}
```

I'm sure someone out there is thinking, "thats a lot of code for this answer, sure seems outrageous".  Well like how `DateTime.Now` should have been a method (because methods return values that could change per call, and property should normally not change values per *call*, see the link above), Age changes per call, so the Property should probably be Birth.  Next I encapsulated the method of determining Age as an Extension method because anything that can be `IBorn` certainly can have an Age (ignore the philosophical question of something is dead, does it have an Age :P).  And lastly, created the `IDateTimeFactory` object so one can unit test the Age method to determine if it's calculating age correctly (otherwise, hardcoding `DateTime.Now` means you can't tell how old something is say compared to something else e.g old is my brother compared to my sister).