# Use a property as factory method

Tags: c#, properties, factory-method

I have a base class `Base` which needs to create instances of another type `TRequired`, however, only derived classes from `Base` know how to construct those.

Is it bad style to use an abstract property as factory method? e.g.

```
protected abstract TRequired NewTRequired { get; }
```

Should I use a method for some reason? Is there a guide why I should/shouldn't use a property here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should *definitely* use a method because accessing this member *does* something. Calling a method is a good way to let the code speak for itself in that regard.

Or, if you prefer another perspective: two subsequent accesses of the member will return different results. A good rule of thumb is to use a method whenever this is the case, in order to not violate the [principle of least astonishment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/187457/what-is-the-principle-of-least-astonishment).

This looks like it's reading the result of a variable, even though if you know that `NewTRequired` is a property (as opposed to a field) you also know that in reality it's running arbitrary code:

```
var prototype = Factory.NewTRequired;
```

I have deliberately put the result into a variable called `prototype` in order to better show that even an informed reader of this code can be easily thrown off: it would not be unreasonable to see this and think "right, so `NewTRequired` is the prototype object for X". That reader would certainly be astonished by the result of code like this:

```
var eq = object.ReferenceEquals(prototype, Factory.NewTRequired);
```

Contrast this with a factory method. Now this code might give off a slight smell:

```
// hmmm... are we actually using this as a prototype?
// because it sure looks like an instance created just for the occasion.
var prototype = Factory.NewTRequired();
```

And this code will never astonish you:

```
// obviously should be false, the code screams "I am creating new instances!"
var eq = object.ReferenceEquals(Factory.NewTRequired(), Factory.NewTRequired());
```

A famous example of where this rule really [should have been followed but was not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437972/why-is-datetime-now-a-property-and-not-a-method) is the [`DateTime.Now`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.datetime.now.aspx) property.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend a method instead:

```
protected abstract TRequired CreateRequired();
```

Creation implies "work" occurring.  This is a better fit for a method vs. a property, as a property getter implies something that will typically be returned quickly without executing much code.

Even your question title "property as factory method" implies that a factory method should be a *method*.

Answer (score 4):

Properties are designed for things that "look like" fields, such as the location of an object.

A property that returns a new instance every time you get it is very poor design.

You should use a method instead.