# MVC Entity Framework DropDownListFor<>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I would like to follow best MVC best practise for creating DropLists.

I have 3 Models (I have cut them down for the purposes of this)

Model One
Student

```
public int ID {get;set;}
public string Name {get;set}
public Site SiteID {get;set;}
```

Model Two 
Site

```
public int ID {get;set;}
public string SiteName {get;set}
```

Model Three 
VM

```
public int ID {get;set}
public student Students {get;set;}

public DateTime Date  { get { return DateTime.Now; } }
public bool Criteria {get;set;}
```

In my VM view I am using EditorFor html helpers to populate my VM and Student Models. The site model is pre populated at the database seed.

I am looking for the best way to include a dropdownlist of sites on my VM view, that will map to my student model.

How to I correctly set up my models to achieve this?

Comment: Can you clarify your question, if the model for that would use all three models, you would create a larger view with all of the data.

Comment: On your Model Three VM i'd highly recommend changing [Date from a property to a method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437972/why-is-datetime-now-a-property-and-not-a-method).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, you want the [DropDownListFor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703462%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) extension method and to put a `List<Site>` into the view model.

Here is a [Fiddle that demonstrates your case](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BdMh6v). The Fiddle has more details. The nuts and bolts are here:

### ViewModel - Add a `List<Site>`

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        this.Sites = new List<Site>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set;}
    public Student Students { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date  { get { return DateTime.Now; } }
    public bool Criteria { get; set; }      

    public List<Site> Sites { get; set; }
}
```

## View - Use `DropDownListFor`

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Sites, 
    new SelectList(Model.Sites, "ID", "SiteName"))
```

In psuedo-code, the above says

- The `Sites` object in the model contains the properties to display.
- Create a new `SelectList` using the `Sites` object in the model. Use the `ID` property as the data value and the `SiteName` property as the data text.
- Create a drop down list based on the above info.

## Controller

This just passes a seeded view model to the view.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var vm = SeedFromDatabase();
    return View(vm);
}

private MyViewModel SeedFromDatabase()
{
    var vm = new MyViewModel();
    vm.Sites.Add(new Site(0, "one"));
    vm.Sites.Add(new Site(1, "two"));
    vm.Sites.Add(new Site(2, "three"));
    return vm;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ViewModel

```
public class VM
{
    public int ID {get;set}
    public student Students {get;set;}

    public SelectList SiteList {get;set;}
    public int SiteID {get;set;}

    public DateTime Date  { get { return DateTime.Now; } }
    public bool Criteria {get;set;}
}
```

Load View Action

```
public ActionResult LoadVMView(){      
     var model = new VM();

     var items = GetSitesFromDatabase().Select(s => new SelectListItem(){
                        Text = s.SiteName,
                        Value = s.ID.ToString()
                        });
 model.SiteList = new SelectList(items);

      return View(model);
}
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SiteID, Model.SiteList)
```

On Post

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LoadVMView(VM model){

var selecteSiteID = model.SiteID;
}
```

Comment: This is a good approach, though it doesn't build as it currently stands. It needs quite a bit of work before it will build.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin the answer is just to guide how the DropDownListFor works, That is what the OP asked in Question

Comment: It doesn't build. For instance, you cannot use `ToList()` to assign to a `SelectList`.

Comment: Also, you cannot implicitly convert `int` to `string`.

Comment: There is a missing semi-colon in your property.

Comment: The `Student` model has a property `ID` not `Id`.

Comment: There are other errors too. When it builds, comment again, and I'll delete my existing comments and provide an up vote.