# Using SelectList in Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, selectlist

My database contains two tables , one with my types and another master table for UI with some data having a column of myid from my types.

```
   myTable
**myid   myname**
1    firstname
2    x-name
99   randomename
 ....

mastertable used in view

id  onecol  twocol refcol <- col is refering mytable
1     xyz    abc   2        <-value 2 is myid of mytable
```

....
In view of , I need to show the all myName instead of Id but update the master table with id. So I setup as follows:-

My  controller in asp.net setup some SelectList and passed to ViewBag like

```
ViewBag.myType = new SelectList(tableList, "myId", "myName");
```

In the View I used

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.myType, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">            
        @Html.DropDownList("myType", ViewBag.myType as SelectList,"-Select-", new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.myType)
    </div>
```

The above working well but in controller I didnt getthe myId, and is undefined when i look in browser before passing to controller. like  below. i tried.

In script to pass controller I used

```
$(".form-group").each(function () {
    if ($(this).find('select').length > 0) {
       attrName = $(this).find('select').attr("name");
        if (attrName == "myType") {       
              //the below is returning undefined 
// the value are undefined for all items as look into chrome debug tool for the list
              //        paramList[attrName] = $(this).find('select').val(); 

//so i used the below that is returning correct text selected
                    var myName = $("#myType option:selected").text();
                    //i need somehwat below, whihc is not correct syntactically
                    var myVal = @{ ((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.myType).Where(x => x.Value == @:myVal).First();}                        
                    //need to pass value, but is 0 in controller.
                    paramList[attrName] = myVal; 
                }
```

Comment: What do you get in:      var myName = $("#myType option:selected").val();

Comment: @Hi Dawood, I got: undefined
myName
"undefined"

Comment: Then what is myId in: ViewBag.myType = new SelectList(tableList, "myId", "myName"); Make sure that the myId and the name of your column are same. e.g. If your column name is: CompanyId, then  new SelectList(tableList, "CompanyId", "myName");

Comment: yes it is column name property in class.
      public partial class mylog
    {
        public int myId { get; set; }
        public string myName { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }        
        public string myType { get; set; }
    }
 and 
  public IEnumerable<mylog> getMyNameList();
        {
            return this.myRepository.getMyNameList();
        }
  
  public IEnumerable<mylog> getMyNameList()
        {
            return this.context.myLog.ToList();
        }
    var tableList = this.MyManager.getMyNameList();

Comment: Please post this code along with the code from your controller in the Question:

Comment: Thanks Awan, your answer below worked :)

Comment: Working code till now  is : var list = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.myType))
   var myName = $("#myType option:selected").text().trim();

                    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {

                        if (list[i].Text ==myName) {

                            //debugger;
                            paramList[attrName] = list[i].Value; //yes I  need this Value to pass, and getting it correctly here.
                        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the Answer to your question, but it is a mistake which I must point out:

```
var myVal = @{ ((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.myType).Where(x => x.Value == @:myVal).First();}
```

This Code is Razor and JavaScript mixed together.

Note that this is wrong:

JavaScript is a client side programming language, while Razor is a Server side.

When a user will access your page you server (IIS) will generate an HTML page based on the Razor you have coded return to the client.

So when this function is called/executed on the client:

```
$(".form-group").each(function () {
```

It will not be able to execute this line:

```
var myVal = @{ ((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.myType).Where(x => x.Value == @:myVal).First();}
```

If you want to access this `ViewBag.myType` on the client, you can convert it to JSON:

*NOTE: Code below has not been tested*

```
<script>

var list = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.myType))

$(".form-group").each(function () {
.....
// Other Code
var myName = $("#myType option:selected").text();

for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){   

if(list[i].Text == myName ){


alert('Match Found');

}

}
</script>
```

**Summary:** You can't execute Razor code using JavaScript on the Client.

**ANSWER:**

What you should do is post the List to the View in `ViewBag`

Controller:

```
ViewBag.MydropDown = tableList;
```

View:

```
    @{
        var items = (IEnumerable<myTable>)ViewBag.MydropDown; 
     }

// Note make sure that Property Names are correct in below line  

    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.myType, new SelectList(items, "myId","myName"), "--Select--", new{@class = "form-control"})
```

Comment: Thanks you Dawood Awan, the above suggestion worked for me. I am able to fix the issue with the path shown. Regards,

Comment: Did you use the above JavaScript method to get it working?

Comment: @AKS My answer is not the best way to solve this though, I was pointing out the mistake in the Razor and JavaScript.

Comment: @AKS you should really do it like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29947587/mvc-enitity-framework-dropdownlistfor/29947770#29947770

Comment: @Awan, for var items = IEnumerable<myTable>(ViewBag.MydropDown);  I did var items = IEnumerable<MyApp.Models.mylog>(ViewBag.MydropDown); 
       Error: 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MyApp.Models.mylog>' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'

Comment: @Awan, I did the edit, it run now. But looks the javascript is still required as  var myName = $("#myType option:selected").val();  is still undefined.

Comment: What if you do? $("#myType).val();

Comment: $("#myType).val(); is undefined. var xy = $("#myType).val(); xy is undefined.

Comment: I tried this on chrome and found  $(myType) gives below
   <select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field my Type must be a number." data-val-required="Please Select my Type." id="myType" name="myType">
   <option value="undefined">oneVal</option><option value="undefined">second_val><option value="undefined">some_val</option>
   .....
   <option value="undefined">last_val</option></select>